# Does using an extended cache improve performance?

Tags: usb, ram, bcache

Does using a extended cache (readyboost-like) improves the overall performance? I read a lot about it and some says that it's just for old machines with low RAM and also the 480mbit/s of usb2.0 was just too slow for cache, and others says that it improves no matter if you got high amounts of ram.

I ask this, because the answers that I found were from a time where usb3.0 was not a standart thing like it's now.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, extended cache is popular for folks with large databases, and research by [Kang, Lee and Moon](http://vldb.org/pvldb/vol5/p1615_woon-hakkang_vldb2012.pdf) describes how custom coding to take advantage of flash memory can speed up PostgreSQL.

[Bcache's author](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/) says it's dandy for RAID6 users, but his raw data also shows inconsistant performance as block sizes decrease, and he did not use USB3, he used an SSD on a SATA cable.

Therefore, I would say yes if you were running with RAID6 or PostgreSQL with the Kang, Lee and Moon code, but questionable otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer kiloseven. So i guess that for a home user there will be no diference at all...

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe now, you could measure it and see, but I don't see anything published that's definitive.